# Do Hindu Texts Say Wild Animals Come Close To Yogis

Tags: animals, yogi

I recall Vivekanand saying wild animals that are ferocious will become calm around yogi types.

Do Hindu texts say clearly that wild animals will come close to yogis, be unafraid of them ? I mean wild animals that would shy away from a normal average ordinary person. Like wild birds, lions, etc

Vaguely remember hearing this, like jaguars and leopards walking up to them without fear.

Edit : I mean like very advanced yogis in India in the mountains and forests and such.

Comment: I don't know if it was explicitly mentioned anywhere, but many stories about sages show similar environment. I remember reading this phrase, "In his/ their presence wild animals renounced their ferocious nature and snakes left their venomous nature. Prey and Predator drink water side by side."  Unfortunately I cannot remember where I read that.

Comment: @xax Thx for your comment, and yeah, I can’t remember where I read it either but I heard the same, how wild animals are not afraid of them, wild birds come near them, things like that.

Comment: @devibhakt I searched the SV's CW but couldn't find a related story.Instead i found a similar story by Swami Mukundananda in his book the "Power of Thoughts".In the chapter 1 of this book it states how our thoughts affect our environment.Its a story of a Yogi and swans and how the thoughts of yogi influences the environment and subsequently affects the attitude of swams towards him.You can read it [here](https://libgen.rocks/ads.php?md5=EF2915F1F88806CD12DCF84FDFE07BD8).[note:books is of epub type so pls read it online]

Comment: @Rāmachandra Thx ! :) I will check it out. I love animals so been intrigued by this phenomenon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many stories and tales of wild animals being calmed by ascetics in Indic traditions. You specifically said 'Hindu' text, I would go beyond that identification of 'Hindu' and give reference from a Tibetan Buddhist text
viz. *The Hundred Thousand Songs of Milarepa* by Tsangnyön Heruka. Jetsun Milarepa was very similar to the renunciates (yogins) living in the Greater Himalayas, in the sense that he often wandered in places far from human society in Himalayas, in his case though, in Tibet-Nepal region. And the practice of Kagyu school of Tibetan Buddhism was heavily influenced by yoga and tantra.

> ...*in front of him a deer approached. It was black and every hair in its fur had a silver tip. The deer moved as though it were terrified. Unbearable great compassion arose in the Jetsun’s mind, thinking, “It is by the power of previous bad karma that a body such as this istaken. He has not done anything wrong in this life, yet he must experience such unbearable suffering. What a pity! I will teach the dharma of the Mahāyāna and lead him to eternal happiness.” Then he sang this song of realization to the deer.... By the compassion of the Jetsun, the deer’s fear and suffering were pacified. With tears streaming from his eyes, he relaxed with the Jetsun, licked his clothes, and went to sleep on Milarepa’s left side. The Jetsun thought, “The barking I heard before must have been a ferocious dog that wanted to harm this deer. I wonder what it is like.” Then a female dog appeared, red in color with a black tail and a cord around its neck. All four of her claws were shredded from running on rock, and her tongue was flapping from her mouth like a banner. “This dog that barks ferociously with great aggression and malevolent mind, and that runs, shooting through space like lightning, is who was chasing the deer and wanted to do it harm,” Milarepa thought. “Whatever outer appearing things this dog sees, she takes them as enemies. She’s never free of such aggression; how good it would be if I could pacify her anger.” Then he sang this song of realization to the dog with a heart of great sorrow and compassion for her.  ..This pacified the dog’s aggression. The dog then whimpered and wagged her tail at the Jetsun. Making bowing gestures and licking his clothes, she lay down on his right side, tucking her snout between her two paws. With tears trickling down her face, she and the deer lay there sleeping like a mother and her child.* (see Tsangnyön Heruka, 2017, Chapter-26 : 'Meeting Khyira Repa')

In this chapter, Milarepa is meditating in a forest when a frightened deer runs in front of him, he sings a dharma song, calming the deer down. Moments later, a large angry hunting dog appears who is calmed again by Milarepa with his song of dharma. Finally, a hunter- the dog's owner appeared (*it occurs in continuation with the excerpt*), he is livid to see that his dog and prey(deer) were both sitting calmly in front of Milarepa, but Milarepa calms him too with his song, which was so effective, that he renounced hunting and became a dedicated disciple. Here, both wild animals and humans respond positively when they are presented with dharma. This is merely a story with verses in between, it's hard to show its veracity. In Tibetan biographic tales, it's quite common to have an ascetic pacifying wild animals by teaching the dharma, Milarepa's example, which I cited, is the most famous one.

In popular traditions, there are many such accounts mentioned where yogins calmed wild animals and living calmly with wild leopards and tigers in forests, as you mentioned. I don't know any texts, as of now, which mention such instances explicitly except extremely recent ones (such as those of Svāmīnārāyaṇa and others). If I do find, I may add them perhaps in this answer later.

**Reference**

- Tsangnyön Heruka (2017). *The Hundred Thousand Songs of Milarepa: A New Translation* (C. Stagg & Dzogchen Ponlop, Trans.). Shambhala

Comment: Thx, good to know :) Have been curious about this for some time

Comment: (Only reason didn’t accept your lovely answer is I am looking more for examples from Hindu texts, so like from shastra anc that sort of thing. Like with advanced yogis of Hinduism and such. But thx for taking time to reply though :D

Comment: I understand 